# SDK and android studio issue in flutter doctor

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

How do i resolve these 2 errors in flutter

1. Unable to locate SDK and
2. Android studio directory

**flutterError**
[image: flutterError]

Comment: Are you installing flutter for the first time or did these errors show up after having flutter installed? Do you have the android SDK installed?

Comment: Yes am installing it for the first time
yes i have installed SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you installed Android SDK, also make sure that you setup C:..\android\SDK\tools and C:..\android\plateform-tools in your environment variables

Comment: Thanks my Android Studio error was resolved but i have the tool chain problem please tell me how to resolve that also.
Thanks in advance!!!